# Como trocar a cor de uma div via javascript com uma condição

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando mudar a cor de uma `div` se a seguinte condição for verdadeira, `if( @ViewBag == "reservado" )`, mas não estou conseguindo, alguém poderia me dizer como ficaria o código com essa condição descrita a cima?

Estou programando em Asp.NET

A `div` que quero mudar a cor é esta:

```
<div class="num">001</div>
```

Ultimo código que tentei:

```
function trocaCor(){
    var condi = @ViewBag.status;

    if( condi == "reservado"){
        document.getElementById("num").style.backgroundColor = green;
    }

}
```

mas não sei se esta certo, quero que quando a página for carregada essa condição (se estiver correta) seja executada.

Também tentei o seguinte código:

```
if( @ViewBag == "reservado" ){
    $('.num').css('background-color','#000000');
}
```

Mas não deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Victor, o problema de usar o `Javascript` é que se for um arquivo externo `.js` não vai funcionar, porque o `@ViewBag` só funciona na página `.cshtml` (se for VB, `.vbhtml`).

Uma forma simples seria criar uma classe `css` com o estilo que quer:

```
.reservado {
   background-color: #000000
}
```

No cshtml, faça a condição, e adicione a classe a uma variável se for verdadeira, senão deixe vazio, para não adicionar nenhuma classe:

```
string classeReservado = (@ViewBag.status == "reservado") ? "reservado" : "";
```

Dai, vai da div e usa essa variável para aplicar a classe:

```
<div class="@classeReservado">
```

Se ainda quiser usar `Javascript` e o arquivo for externo, precisa criar a variável dentro do arquivo `.cshtml`, que é processado pelo `asp-net` e consegue ler o conteúdo da `ViewBag`:

```
var condi = '@ViewBag.status';
```

Comment: Ricardo, Obrigago, consegui com o seguinte código:                                       var someStringValue = '@(ViewBag.statusAcomo1)';
                
            if (someStringValue == "reservado") {
                    $('.num1').css('background-color', '#ffa500');
            }